# Check if the first and last row of a matrix has only negative values

Tags: c

i have some problem making this program
I have created two arrays where I go to insert the first and the last line, then I check if every element is > 0 but it doesn't seem to work..

That's my code:

```
int main()

    {
    int i, j, n, m;
    int matrix[10][20];
    int first_row[m];
    int last_row[m];



    printf("Enter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of columns : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    /* Input data in matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter data in [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

            if(matrix[i=0][j]) // First row
            first_row[i] = matrix[i=0][j];

            if(matrix[i=n-1][j]) // second row
            last_row[i] = matrix[i=n-1][j];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=j+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(last_row[i] < 0)
            printf("Negative element");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When `int first_row[m];` occurs, `m` is not initialized nor assigned.  Code is lost as to the array size.  `scanf("%d", &m);` is too late.  Where might be a better place to define `int first_row[m];`?

Comment: ok i fix it but it doesnt work, what i did wrong?

Comment: Tip: Avoid "it doesnt work" - it is far too vague.  State what was inputted, output seen and output expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in the if conditions `matrix[i=0][j]` and `matrix[i=n-1][j]` was to check if the current row being input is the first or last row respectively. If that was the case then you just need to simply check if i is 0 (`i == 0`) or n - 1 (`i == n-1`) instead of using `matrix[i=0][j]` and `matrix[i=n-1][j]`.

Also the line `first_row[i] = matrix[i=0][j];` and `last_row[i] = matrix[i=n-1][j];` will update `i` which is what you should avoid in a for loop where `i` is index. If you intended to assign values to `first_row` and `last_row`, you should change them to `first_row[j] = matrix[0][j];` and `last_row[j] = matrix[n-1][j];` to a get the desire result (note that `j` should be used for indexing `first_row` and `last_row` instead of `i` because `j` represents matrix column).

If you want to check every element in the matrix for negative values, then the for loop `for (j=j+1;j<n;j++)` should be changed to `for (j=0;j<m;j++)` and `matrix[i][j]` should be used instead of `last_row[i]`.

Edit: Also as @chux suggested, you should consider initializing `matrix`, `first_row` and `last_row` arrays after you input `n` and `m` in order to avoid segmentation fault for any `n` and `m` values that are larger than 10 and 20 respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m;

    printf("Enter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of columns : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int matrix[n][m];
    int first_row[m];
    int last_row[m];

    /* Input data in matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter data in [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

            if(i == 0) // First row
                first_row[j] = matrix[0][j];

            if(i == n-1) // second row
                last_row[j] = matrix[n-1][j];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] < 0)
                printf("Negative element %d\n", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow.
Thank you, you helped me understand where I was wrong